# Does Mercurial access the Windows certificate store?

Tags: windows, mercurial, certificate

I'm working to upgrade our source control from hg 1.6.0 to 1.8.2 and I'm looking to set up and use SSL certs.  This is on a Windows Server 2008 Enterprise system running IIS 6.0, not my server so I need to use those versions of software right now.  All my users are running Windows too.

To ease installation/configuration for my users I'd prefer to modify the Windows Cert Store instead of the cacert.pem file.  Does Mercurial have access to the Windows Certificate Store?  It doesn't seem to.  I am using internally created certificates and I can get things to work without SSL warnings by adding my root cert to the cacert.pem file in Mercurial but I can't seem to get it to work by adding the certs to the Windows Cert Store.  Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1):

No, Mercurial does not access the Windows certificate store.
It [includes in its distribution a `cacert.pm`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Windows) (as you know, even though before 1.7.3, the [story was a bit different](http://adblockplus.org/blog/mercurial-over-https-ouch-ssl-isn-t-always-secure))

The article "[X.509 certificates and Mercurial](http://hstuart.dk/2010/04/09/x-509-certificates-and-mercurial/)" has more information.

> A principal thing to remember here is that Mercurial will *not* work as a complete server out of the box, requesting authentication information, in the form of basic, digest, or certificates, at all.
>   This means that in order to use X.509 certificates with Mercurial, one needs to place a web server that knows of these authentication mechanisms in front of it.

This article includes **`makecert.exe`**, which actually knows about the Windows certificates store (contrary to Mercurial itself)

> `makecert.exe` is a bit of a different beast from `openssl` as it interfaces directly with the machine’s or user’s certificate store (the special place where certificates live a happy life in Windows).

Comment: Thanks for that link to the article.  I had used openssl to create my CSR, no idea what the admin used to create the certs from that.  I'll try makecert.exe.  If I use makecert do I need to have client certs or are the root and server certs enough if IIS is set up not to require client certs?

Comment: @user693957: root and server certs ought to be enough, but this need to be tested first.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working.  Even if I add my root cert to the LocalMachine Trusted Root certs the fingerprint of the hg server does not verify.  If I add my root cert to the cacerts file then it's ok.  I'm going to try a few more combinations of different certs and locations but it seems that the cacerts file needs to be modified and that Mercurial/Python do not see the Windows cert store.

Comment: No luck with the Winodws Cert Store, I have found no way for Mercurial to access it.  Modifying the Mercurial cacerts file works just fine.